# How do I use an if... else conditional in the inner loop of a nested list comprehension in Python?

Tags: python, list, nested, conditional-statements, list-comprehension

I'm trying to use an `if... else` conditional for the **inner loop** in of a nested list comprehension in Python, but I keep on getting syntax errors.

This seems to work fine:

```
[<expression> for <variable> in <iterable> for <nested_variable> in <variable> if <expression>]
```

And I know this won't work:

```
[<expression> for <variable> in <iterable> for <nested_variable> in <variable> if <expression> else <expression>]
```

And that's because an `if... else` statement in a list comprehension must be placed before the actual loop, as in:

```
[<expression> if <expression> else <expression> for <variable> in <iterable>
```

But when I try to do the above for the nested loop in my nested list comprehension, I keep getting syntax errors:

```
[<expression> for <variable> in <iterable> if <expression> else <expression> for <nested_variable> in <variable>]
```

I've tried using parentheses to group my loops or something, but I just run into more syntax errors.

Is it possible to use an `if... else` conditional for the **nested loop** in a nested list comprehension in Python?

If so, how?

Comment: What's the `else` supposed to do…?

Comment: The second won't work because you can't have an `else` for the if at the end of the loop. That if means "insert the element in the final list *if* condition is true". The implicit else is "otherwise, skip this item". Don't mix up python's ternary operator with the insertion condition for comprehensions (even if they both look like if statements..)

Comment: @deceze It's not a duplicate since the OP asks for using a conditional for the nested iterable rather than the loop expression. Technically it's similar but concept-wise a bit different.

Comment: @a_guest Without clarification of what that `if..else` is supposed to do exactly (which is unclear to me from the given information), pointing to that dupe is the only sensible thing I can think of.

Comment: @deceze Since the OP already includes the duplicate's answer (`[<expression> if <expression> else <expression> for <variable> in <iterable>`) this is apparently not what they are looking for. In case the question is unclear it should be closed and asking for clarity.